# Getting this error: how can I solve this?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming how can I solve this error could someone help me? tried it by myself but wasn't able to! I tried changing the variable data types but got other errors. Please suggest me what can I do to solve this error.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#define assertm(exp, msg) assert(((void)msg, exp))
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;

typedef double my_float;
typedef std::complex<my_float> my_complex;

typedef std::vector<my_complex> complex_vector;
typedef std::vector<my_float> float_vector;
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;

typedef std::vector<complex_vector> complex_matrix;
typedef std::vector<int_vector> int_matrix;

void scaleVectorInplace(std::vector<my_complex>& V, my_complex scale){
  std::transform(V.begin(), V.end(), V.begin(), [scale](auto s) { return s * scale; });
}

std::vector<my_complex> scaleVector(const std::vector<my_complex>& V, my_complex scale) {
  std::vector<my_complex> result = V;
  scaleVectorInplace(result, scale);
  return result;
}


my_complex qpskmod(int symbol) {
  const std::vector<my_complex> mapping {{1,1},  {-1,1}, {1,-1},  {-1, -1}};
  return mapping[symbol];
}

   int main() {

    int symbol;
  // Modulate one symbol to its QPSK representation
  const complex_vector mapping {{1,1},  {-1,1}, {1,-1},  {-1, -1}};

    int_vector symbols;
  // Modulate a vector of symbols with is QPSK representation
  std::vector<my_complex> result;
  //complex_vector result;

  result.resize(symbols.size());
  // applies QPSK modulation to each symbol in the vector
  std::transform(symbols.begin(), symbols.end(),
         result.begin(), [](int s) { return qpskmod(s); });
  return result;
}
```

Error:

```
In function 'int main()':
55:10: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<std::complex<double> >' to 'int' in return
```

Comment: Think about what `int main()` is supposed to return and what you actually return in `return result;`.

Comment: Please read the error message again. What does it say? What is the declared return type of the `main` function? What are you trying to return? Why are you trying to return that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you possibly trying to print the contents of `result`? Then you need to explicitly do that in your program.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to *return* a vector from `main`. Perhaps you should get yourself [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start at the beginning.

Comment: You are returning **result** wich is not an int. And **main** returns an int.

Comment: I am trying to print the results, tried adding cout but showing an error. or how can I assign the values of qpskmod(s) and can I print it to the console?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I am trying to do that. How could I prin them explicitly? can you please give an example.

Comment: You will have iterate manually over the vector and print each element, because there is no overload for `operator<<` with `std::vector`, i.e. you can't just push a vector an ostream.

Comment: `for (auto value : result) { std::cout << value << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int main()` returns a value of type `int` but you return the variable `result` of type `std::vector<my_complex>`

The return value of `main` indicates if the program terminated successfully (`return 0`) or with some kind of error code but no complex data structure

Catching up your other question from the comments how you can print the values, you might want to use a simple function for that like:

```
void printResult(std::vector<my_complex> &vec)
{
   std::vector<my_complex>::iterator itr = vec.begin();

   while (itr != vec.end())
   {
      std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
      itr++;
   }
}
```

The end of your `main` function could then look like:

```
printResult(result);
return EXIT_SUCCESS; // most likely same as return 0
```

You might also add a condition at the end for `return EXIT_FAILURE` instead